# How to get boost::asio::io_service current action number

Tags: c++, boost-asio

Boost::asio::io_service provides "handler tracking" for debugging purposes, it is enabled by defining BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING but logs its data to stderr. I'd like to use this tracking information in my application. My question is what is the best way to get access to the `<action>` inside my application?

For more context as to *why* I want to do this; I would like to attach the `<action>` as a parameter to other async operations so that I can track where the originating request came from.

Comment: Even if this is possible, I guess this will result in performance decrease. Why can't you use your own identifier which you pass on from async op to async op?

Comment: I'm with m.s. Perhaps even include an activity ID as a GUID so you can trace related activity across servers/clients

Comment: My first option was to roll my own but it felt like a dirty hack. Seeing that boost had done all most all the work I thought some boost guru would have some esoteric solution.

Comment: One reason this 'hack' is appealing as it allows quick'n'dirty debugging of the call graph - without having to modify every call site and sending this info somewhere other than cerr stream (eg the logger already part of an application) would be handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example that mimics asio debug handler tracking. Caveats:

1. Assumes ioService only run from a single thread. I never use any other way so I'm not sure what needs to change to fix this limitation.
2. Non-thread safe access to `std::cerr` - fixing this left as an exercise.

**Code**:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/atomic.hpp>

#include <iostream>

class HandlerTracking
{
public:

    HandlerTracking()
        :
        mCount(1)
    { }


    template <class Handler>
    class WrappedHandler
    {
    public:

        WrappedHandler(HandlerTracking& t, Handler h, std::uint64_t id) 
            : 
            mHandlerTracking(t), 
            mHandler(h),
            mId(id)
        { }

        WrappedHandler(const WrappedHandler& other)
            :
            mHandlerTracking(other.mHandlerTracking),
            mHandler(other.mHandler),
            mId(other.mId),
            mInvoked(other.mInvoked)
        {
            other.mInvoked = true;
        }

        ~WrappedHandler()
        {
            if (!mInvoked)
                std::cerr << '~' << mId << std::endl;
        }

        template <class... Args>
        void operator()(Args... args)
        {
            mHandlerTracking.mCurrHandler = mId;
            std::cerr << '>' << mId << std::endl;

            try
            {
                mInvoked = true;
                mHandler(args...); 
            }
            catch(...)
            {
                std::cerr << '!' << mId << std::endl;
                throw;
            }
            std::cerr << '<' << mId << std::endl;
        }

        const std::uint64_t id() { return mId; }

    private:

        HandlerTracking& mHandlerTracking;
        Handler mHandler;
        const std::uint64_t mId;
        mutable bool mInvoked = false;
    };

    template <class Handler>
    WrappedHandler<Handler> wrap(Handler handler) 
    {
        auto next = mCount.fetch_add(1);
        std::cerr << mCurrHandler << '*' << next << std::endl;
        return WrappedHandler<Handler>(*this, handler, next);
    }

    boost::atomic<std::uint64_t> mCount;
    std::uint64_t mCurrHandler = 0;           // Note: If ioService run on multiple threads we need a curr handler per thread
};


// Custom invokation hook for wrapped handlers
//template <typename Function, typename Handler>
//void asio_handler_invoke(Function f, HandlerTracking::WrappedHandler<Handler>* h)
//{
//    std::cerr << "Context: " << h << ", " << h->id() << ", " << f.id() << std::endl;
//    f();
//}


// Class to demonstrate callback with arguments
class MockSocket
{
public:

    MockSocket(boost::asio::io_service& ioService) : mIoService(ioService) {}

    template <class Handler>
    void async_read(Handler h)
    {
        mIoService.post([h]() mutable { h(42); }); // we always read 42 bytes
    }

private:
    boost::asio::io_service& mIoService;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    boost::asio::io_service ioService;
    HandlerTracking tracking;

    MockSocket socket(ioService);

    std::function<void()> f1 = [&]() { std::cout << "Handler1" << std::endl; };
    std::function<void()> f2 = [&]() { std::cout << "Handler2" << std::endl; ioService.post(tracking.wrap(f1)); };
    std::function<void()> f3 = [&]() { std::cout << "Handler3" << std::endl; ioService.post(tracking.wrap(f2)); };
    std::function<void()> f4 = [&]() { std::cout << "Handler4" << std::endl; ioService.post(tracking.wrap(f3)); };

    std::function<void(int)> s1 = [](int s) { std::cout << "Socket read " << s << " bytes" << std::endl; };

    socket.async_read(tracking.wrap(s1)); 

    ioService.post(tracking.wrap(f1));
    ioService.post(tracking.wrap(f2));
    ioService.post(tracking.wrap(f3));
    auto tmp = tracking.wrap(f4);  // example handler destroyed without invocation

    ioService.run();



    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

```
0*1
0*2
0*3
0*4
0*5
>1
Socket read 42 bytes
<1
>2
Handler1
<2
>3
Handler2
3*6
<3
>4
Handler3
4*7
<4
>6
Handler1
<6
>7
Handler2
7*8
<7
>8
Handler1
<8
~5
```

Comment: a question that came to mind while working on the above answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32857101/424153

Comment: Nice work!  Just to note two more caveats: it does not handle intermediate handlers and it does not handle subsequent calls to run the `io_service`.  Here is a [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eed6a554d88b98eb) with the output from both tracking methods.

Comment: I'm using the above in production - when (if?) I improve it as per your suggestions I'll update the answer. Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 4):

Asio does not expose its handler tracking data.  Attempting to extract the tracking information contained within Asio would be far more of a dirty hack than rolling ones own custom handler.

Here is a snippet from Asio's [handler tracking](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/boost-1.58.0/include/boost/asio/detail/handler_tracking.hpp):

```cpp
namespace boost {
namespace asio {
namespace detail {

class handler_tracking
{
public:
  class completion;

  // Base class for objects containing tracked handlers.
  class tracked_handler
  {
  private:
    // Only the handler_tracking class will have access to the id.
    friend class handler_tracking;
    friend class completion;
    uint64_t id_;

  // ...

  private:
    friend class handler_tracking;
    uint64_t id_;
    bool invoked_;
    completion* next_;
  };

// ...

private:
  struct tracking_state;
  static tracking_state* get_state();
};

} // namespace detail
} // namespace asio
} // namespace boost
```

---

As others have mentioned, passing a GUID throughout the handlers would allow one to associate multiple asynchronous operations.  One non-intrusive way to accomplish this is to create a custom tracking handler type that wraps existing handlers and manages the tracking data.  For an example on custom handlers, see the Boost.Asio [Invocation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html#boost_asio.examples.cpp03_examples.invocation) example.

Also, be aware that if a custom handler type is used, one should be very careful when composing handlers.  In particular, the custom handler type's invocation hook ([`asio_handler_invoke()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/asio_handler_invoke.html)) may need to account for the context of other handlers.  For example, if one does not explicitly account for wrapped handler returned from [`strand::wrap()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand/wrap.html), then it will prevent intermediate operations from running in the correct context for composed operations.  To avoid having to explicitly handle this, one can wrap the custom handler by `strand::wrap()`:

```cpp
boost::asio::async_read(..., strand.wrap(tracker.wrap(&handle_read))); // Good.
boost::asio::async_read(..., tracker.wrap(strand.wrap(&handle_read))); // Bad.
```

Comment: Awesome, as usual. Would you consider the in transparancy of handler composition a library flaw? I think I do (although I think I can the reasons not to "solve" it with explicit handler mechanics). It's  certainly a pitfall that's really hard to document well.

Comment: @sehe Thanks.  I do not consider it a flaw, but it is one area where both the API and documentation could be improved.  While the documentation covers all the details, I think users would greatly benefit with an explicit example, rather than it being left as an exercise for users to piece together all of the pieces.  Also, I do like the API changes in the development release of Asio ([change history](http://think-async.com/asio/asio-1.11.0/doc/asio/history.html#asio.history.asio_1_11_0)), as it becomes easier to bind and obtain the executor context for handlers.