# When to use `asio_handler_invoke`?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

**Question**

When is it necessary to use `asio_handler_invoke` to achieve something that cannot be done by simply wrapping the handler?

A canonical example that demonstrates a case where `asio_handler_invoke` is required would be ideal.

**Background**

The boost asio docs contain an example of *how* to use `asio_handler_invoke` [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/invocation/prioritised_handlers.cpp), but I don't think it is a compelling example of *why* you would use the invocation handler. In that example it appears you could make changes like the following (and remove the `asio_handler_invoke`) and achieve an identical result:

```
template <typename Arg1>
void operator()(Arg1 arg1)
{
  queue_.add(priority_, std::bind(handler_, arg1));
}
```

Similarly, in my answer relating to [handler tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32856299/424153) it similarly appears unnecessary to use `asio_handler_invoke`, despite [Tanner Sansbury's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31456292/424153) answer suggesting using the invocation hook as a solution.

[This thread](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/boost-asio-reason-for-asio-handler-invoke-td2574233.html) on the boost user group provides some more information - but I don't understand the significance.

From what I have seen, it appears `asio_handler_invoke` is always called like `asio_handler_invoke(h, &h)`, which doesn't appear to make much sense. In what cases would the arguments not be (essentially) copies of the same object?

A final point - I only ever call `io_service::run()` from a single thread, so it may be I'm missing something obvious that comes from experience in a multi-threaded loop.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In short, wrapping a handler and `asio_handler_invoke` accomplish two different tasks:

- wrap a handler to customize the invocation of a handler.
- define `asio_handler_invoke` hook to customize the invocation of *other handlers* in the context of a handler.

```cpp
template <typename Handler>
struct custom_handler
{
  void operator()(...); // Customize invocation of handler_.
  Handler handler_;
};

// Customize invocation of Function within context of custom_handler.
template <typename Function>
void asio_handler_invoke(Function function, custom_handler* context);

// Invoke custom invocation of 'perform' within context of custom_handler.
void perform() {...}
custom_handler handler;
using boost::asio::asio_handler_invoke;
asio_handler_invoke(std::bind(&perform), &handler);
```

The primary reason for the `asio_handler_invoke` hook is to allow one to customize the invocation strategy of handlers to which the application may not have direct access.  For instance, consider composed operations that are composed of zero or more calls to intermediate operations.  For each intermediate operation, an intermediate handler will be created on behalf of the application, but the application does not have direct access to these handlers.  When using custom handlers, the `asio_handler_invoke` hook provides a way to customize the invocation strategy of these intermediate handlers within a given context.  The [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/asio_handler_invoke.html) states:

> When asynchronous operations are composed from other asynchronous operations, all intermediate handlers should be invoked using the same method as the final handler. This is required to ensure that user-defined objects are not accessed in a way that may violate the guarantees. This [`asio_handler_invoke`] hooking function ensures that the invoked method used for the final handler is accessible at each intermediate step.

---

### `asio_handler_invoke`

Consider a case where we wish to count the number of asynchronous operations executed, including each intermediate operation in composed operations.  To do this, we need to create a custom handler type, `counting_handler`, and count the number of times functions are invoked within its context:

```cpp
template <typename Handler>
class counting_handler
{
  void operator()(...)
  {
    // invoke handler
  } 
  Handler handler_;
};

template <typename Function>
void asio_handler_invoke(Function function, counting_handler* context)
{
  // increment counter
  // invoke function
}

counting_handler handler(&handle_read);
boost::asio::async_read(socket, buffer, handler);
```

In the above snippet, the function `handle_read` is wrapped by `counting_handler`.  As the `counting_handler` is not interested in counting the number of times the wrapped handler is invoked, its `operator()` will not increment the count and just invoke `handle_read`.  However, the `counting_handler` is interested in the amount of handlers invoked within its context in the `async_read` operation, so the custom invocation strategy in `asio_handler_invoke` will increment a count.

---

### Example

Here is a concrete example based on the above `counting_handler` type.  The `operation_counter` class provides a way to easily wrap application handlers with a `counting_handler`:

```cpp
namespace detail {

/// @brief counting_handler is a handler that counts the number of
///        times a handler is invoked within its context.
template <class Handler>
class counting_handler
{
public:
  counting_handler(Handler handler, std::size_t& count)
    : handler_(handler),
      count_(count)
  {}

  template <class... Args>
  void operator()(Args&&... args)
  {
    handler_(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }

  template <typename Function>
  friend void asio_handler_invoke(
    Function intermediate_handler,
    counting_handler* my_handler)
  {
    ++my_handler->count_;
    // Support chaining custom strategies incase the wrapped handler
    // has a custom strategy of its own.
    using boost::asio::asio_handler_invoke;
    asio_handler_invoke(intermediate_handler, &my_handler->handler_);
  }

private:
  Handler handler_;
  std::size_t& count_;
};

} // namespace detail

/// @brief Auxiliary class used to wrap handlers that will count
///        the number of functions invoked in their context.
class operation_counter
{
public:

  template <class Handler>
  detail::counting_handler<Handler> wrap(Handler handler)
  {
    return detail::counting_handler<Handler>(handler, count_);
  }

  std::size_t count() { return count_; }

private:
  std::size_t count_ = 0;
};

...

operation_counter counter;
boost::asio::async_read(socket, buffer, counter.wrap(&handle_read));
io_service.run();
std::cout << "Count of async_read_some operations: " <<
             counter.count() << std::endl;
```

The [`async_read()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read/overload1.html) composed operation will be implemented in zero or more intermediate [`stream.async_read_some()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_read_some.html) operations.  For each of these intermediate operations, a handler with an unspecified type will be created and invoked.  If the above `async_read()` operation was implemented in terms of `2` intermediate `async_read_some()` operations, then `counter.count()` will be `2`, and the handler returned from `counter.wrap()` got invoked once.

On the other hand, if one were to not provide an `asio_handler_invoke` hook and instead only incremented the count within the wrapped handler's invocation, then the count would be `1`, reflecting only the count of times the wrapped handler was invoked:

```cpp
template <class Handler>
class counting_handler
{
public:
  ...

  template <class... Args>
  void operator()(Args&&... args)
  {
    ++count_;
    handler_(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }

  // No asio_handler_invoke implemented.
};
```

---

Here is a complete example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17639e6f039ab9ae) counting the number of asynchronous operations that get executed, including intermediate operations from a composed operation.  The example only initiates three async operations (`async_accept`, `async_connect`, and `async_read`), but the `async_read` operation will be composed of `2` intermediate `async_read_some` operations:

```cpp
#include <functional> // std::bind
#include <iostream>   // std::cout, std::endl
#include <utility>    // std::forward
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

// This example is not interested in the handlers, so provide a noop function
// that will be passed to bind to meet the handler concept requirements.
void noop() {}

namespace detail {

/// @brief counting_handler is a handler that counts the number of
///        times a handler is invoked within its context.
template <class Handler>
class counting_handler
{
public:
  counting_handler(Handler handler, std::size_t& count)
    : handler_(handler),
      count_(count)
  {}

  template <class... Args>
  void operator()(Args&&... args)
  {
    handler_(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }

  template <typename Function>
  friend void asio_handler_invoke(
    Function function,
    counting_handler* context)
  {
    ++context->count_;
    // Support chaining custom strategies incase the wrapped handler
    // has a custom strategy of its own.
    using boost::asio::asio_handler_invoke;
    asio_handler_invoke(function, &context->handler_);
  }

private:
  Handler handler_;
  std::size_t& count_;
};

} // namespace detail

/// @brief Auxiliary class used to wrap handlers that will count
///        the number of functions invoked in their context.
class operation_counter
{
public:

  template <class Handler>
  detail::counting_handler<Handler> wrap(Handler handler)
  {
    return detail::counting_handler<Handler>(handler, count_);
  }

  std::size_t count() { return count_; }

private:
  std::size_t count_ = 0;
};

int main()
{
  using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
  operation_counter all_operations;

  // Create all I/O objects.
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;
  tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 0));
  tcp::socket socket1(io_service);
  tcp::socket socket2(io_service);

  // Connect the sockets.
  // operation 1: acceptor.async_accept
  acceptor.async_accept(socket1, all_operations.wrap(std::bind(&noop)));
  // operation 2: socket2.async_connect
  socket2.async_connect(acceptor.local_endpoint(),
      all_operations.wrap(std::bind(&noop)));
  io_service.run();
  io_service.reset();

  // socket1 and socket2 are connected.  The scenario below will:
  // - write bytes to socket1.
  // - initiate a composed async_read operaiton to read more bytes
  //   than are currently available on socket2.  This will cause
  //   the operation to  complete with multple async_read_some 
  //   operations on socket2.
  // - write more bytes to socket1.

  // Write to socket1.
  std::string write_buffer = "demo";
  boost::asio::write(socket1, boost::asio::buffer(write_buffer));

  // Guarantee socket2 has received the data.
  assert(socket2.available() == write_buffer.size());

  // Initiate a composed operation to more data than is immediately
  // available.  As some data is available, an intermediate async_read_some
  // operation (operation 3) will be executed, and another async_read_some 
  // operation (operation 4) will eventually be initiated.
  std::vector<char> read_buffer(socket2.available() + 1);
  operation_counter read_only;
  boost::asio::async_read(socket2, boost::asio::buffer(read_buffer),
    all_operations.wrap(read_only.wrap(std::bind(&noop))));

  // Write more to socket1.  This will cause the async_read operation
  // to be complete.
  boost::asio::write(socket1, boost::asio::buffer(write_buffer));

  io_service.run();
  std::cout << "total operations: " << all_operations.count() << "\n"
               "read operations: " << read_only.count() << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```cpp
total operations: 4
read operations: 2
```

### Composed Handlers

In the above example, the `async_read()` handler was composed of a handler wrapped twice.  First by the `operation_counter` that is only counting for read operations, and then the resulting functor was wrapped by the `operation_counter` counting all operations:

```cpp
boost::asio::async_read(..., all_operations.wrap(read_only.wrap(...)));
```

The `counting_handler`'s `asio_handler_invoke` implementation is written to support composition by invoking the Function in the context of the wrapped handler's context.  This results in the appropriate counting occurred for each `operation_counter`:

```cpp
template <typename Function>
void asio_handler_invoke(
  Function function,
  counting_handler* context)
{
  ++context->count_;
  // Support chaining custom strategies incase the wrapped handler
  // has a custom strategy of its own.
  using boost::asio::asio_handler_invoke;
  asio_handler_invoke(function, &context->handler_);
}
```

On the other hand, if the `asio_handler_invoke` explicitly called `function()`, then only the outer most wrapper's invocation strategy would be invoked.  In this case, it would result in `all_operations.count()` being `4` and `read_only.count()` being `0`:

```cpp
template <typename Function>
void asio_handler_invoke(
  Function function,
  counting_handler* context)
{
  ++context->count_;
  function(); // No chaining.
}
```

When composing handlers, be aware that the `asio_handler_invoke` hook that gets invoked is located through [argument-dependent lookup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup), so it is based on the exact handler type.  Composing handlers with types that are not `asio_handler_invoke` aware will prevent the chaining of invocation strategies.  For instance, using `std::bind()` or `std::function` will result in the default `asio_handler_invoke` being called, causing custom invocation strategies from being invoked:

```cpp
// Operations will not be counted.
boost::asio::async_read(..., std::bind(all_operations.wrap(...)));
```

Proper chaining invocation strategies for composed handlers can be very important.  For example, the unspecified handler type returned from [`strand.wrap()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand/wrap.html) provides the guarantee that initial handler wrapped by the strand and functions invoked in the context of the returned handler will not run concurrently.  This allows one to meet the thread-safety requirements of many of the I/O objects when using composed operations, as the `strand` can be used to synchronize with these intermediate operations to which the application does not have access.

When running the `io_service` by multiple threads, the below snippet may invoke undefined behavior, as the intermediate operations for both composed operations may run concurrently, as `std::bind()` will not invoke the appropriate `asio_handler_hook`:

```cpp
boost::asio::async_read(socket, ..., std::bind(strand.wrap(&handle_read)));
boost::asio::async_write(socket, ..., std::bind(strand.wrap(&handle_write)));
```

Comment: Outstanding answer. But I cannot upvote it more than once. So I started a bounty with this message : *"One or more of the answers is exemplary and **worthy of an additional bounty**."*