# Boost.Asio async_write and strands

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I 'm using a strand to avoid concurrent writes on TCP server using `Boost.Asio`. But it seems it only prevents concurrent execution of handlers.

Indeed if I do two successive `async_write`, one with a very big packet, and the other with a very small one, wireshark shows interleaves. As `async_write` is composed of multiple calls of `async_write_some`, it seems that the handler of my second write is allowed to be executed between two handlers of the first call. Which is very bad for me.

*Wireshark output*: [Packet 1.1] [Packet 1.2] [**Packet 2**] [Packet 1.3] ... [Packet 1.x]

```cpp
struct Command
{
    // Header
    uint64_t ticket_id; // UUID
    uint32_t data_size; // size of data

    // data
    std::vector<unsigned char> m_internal_buffer;
}
typedef std::shared_ptr<Command> command_type;
```

```cpp
void tcp_server::write(command_type cmd)
{
    boost::asio::async_write(m_socket, boost::asio::buffer(cmd->getData(), cmd->getTotalPacketSize()),
        boost::asio::bind_executor(m_write_strand,
            [this, cmd](const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
            {
                if (error)
                {
                   // report
                }
            }
        )
    );
}
```

and the main:

```cpp
int main()
{
    tcp_server.write(big_packet); // Packet 1 = 10 MBytes !
    tcp_server.write(small_packet); // Packet 2 = 64 kbytes
}
```

Is the strand not appropriate in my case ?

P.S: I saw that close topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016135/asioasync-write-and-strand) but it does not cover the same use case in my opinion.

Comment: You have to make sure your async operation is initiated from the strand. Your code currently doesn't show this to be the case. Hopefully this helps, otherwise, post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: There's also the off-chance that the command objects accidentally share resources which, without synchronization, can also lead to corruption. But for my answer I assumed this not to be the case

Comment: @sehe Correct, my operation was NOT initiated from the strand. That might be the issue. The commands objects are correctly synchronized with mutexes in the backend, this is not an issue but you are right to point it out also.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure your async operation is initiated from the strand. Your code currently doesn't show this to be the case. Hopefully this helps, otherwise, post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

So e.g.

```
void tcp_server::write(command_type cmd)
{
    post(m_write_strand, [this, cmd] { this->do_write(cmd); });
}
```

Making up a MCVE from your question code:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/468b13370ad8c2fa)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using Executor = boost::asio::thread_pool::executor_type;

struct command {
    char const* getData()            const { return ""; }
    size_t      getTotalPacketSize() const { return 1;  }
};
using command_type = command*;

struct tcp_server {
    tcp_server(Executor ex) : m_socket(ex), m_write_strand(ex)
    {
        // more?
    }
    void write(command_type cmd);
    void do_write(command_type cmd);

    tcp::socket m_socket;
    boost::asio::strand<Executor> m_write_strand;
};

void tcp_server::write(command_type cmd)
{
    post(m_write_strand, [this, cmd] { this->do_write(cmd); });
}

void tcp_server::do_write(command_type cmd)
{
    boost::asio::async_write(
        m_socket,
        boost::asio::buffer(cmd->getData(), cmd->getTotalPacketSize()),
        bind_executor(m_write_strand,
                      [/*this, cmd*/](boost::system::error_code error,
                                      size_t bytes_transferred) {
                          if (error) {
                              // report
                          }
                      }));
}

int main() {
    boost::asio::thread_pool ioc;
    tcp_server tcp_server(ioc.get_executor());

    command_type big_packet{}, small_packet{};
    tcp_server.write(big_packet);   // Packet 1 = 10 MBytes !
    tcp_server.write(small_packet); // Packet 2 = 64 kbytes

    ioc.join();
}
```

Comment: Your solution makes sense, but does not work in my case (small packet still shows in the middle of others). I will get back here with another MVCE that shows the problem. Thanks anyway for your effort, that's much appreciated.